# Am I breaking the rules of hooks in this component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a counter variable that I need updated using an interval. The issue that I ran into was that `setInterval` doesn't have access to a component current state. Upon looking for ways around this I stumbled on a blog post from Dan Abramov that implements a custom hook to circumvent this issue.

However, upon using his code I immediately was faced with this error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

From what I can tell I'm not violating any of the hook rules and I used several of the react sites debugging methods to see if I had duplicate versions of react. From the code below is there a hook rule I'm breaking that I don't know about?

The only thing I can think of is the error is because I'm calling `useInterval` from inside `useEffect`. If that's the case, how would you set up an interval like this so it starts only once on mount?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { VictoryPie } from "victory";

// styles
import styles from './logConfirmation.module.css';

// custom
import { useInterval } from "../../hooks/useInterval";

const LogConfirmation = props => {
    // props
    const { oldScore, newScore } = props;
    // local
    const [ score, setScore ] = useState(oldScore);
    const [ data, setData ] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const difference = 100/((newScore - (score || 0))*Math.sqrt(.01));
        useInterval(()=>{
            setScore(score < newScore ? score + 1 : newScore);
        }, difference);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        setData([{ x: 1, y: score }, { x: 2, y: 100 - score }]);
    }, [score]);

    return (
        <div id='selectionModal' className={styles.container}>
            <div className={styles.score}>
                <div className="wellness-circle">
                    <div className="circle-inner d:f a-i:c">
                        <h2 className='t-a:c'><span className='plus'>+</span>{score.current}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className="circle-outer">
                        <VictoryPie
                            innerRadius={200}
                            cornerRadius={50}
                            data={data}
                            labels={() => null}
                            style={{
                                data: {
                                    fill: (d) => {
                                        let color;
                                        if(d.y < 50) color = "#fff";
                                        if(d.y > 49 && d.y < 76) color = "#fff";
                                        if(d.y > 75) color = "#fff";
                                        return d.x === 1 ? color : 'transparent';
                                    }
                                }
                            }}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2 className={styles.points}>[+5 Points]</h2>
            <p className={styles.pointsBottom}>Total points earned for this today</p>
            <div className={styles.streak}>
                <div>
                    <h4 className={styles.streakTitle}>You're on a streak!</h4>
                    <p className={styles.streakTag}>[11 days straight. Nice :)]</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default LogConfirmation;
```

`useInterval.js`

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

 export function useInterval(callback, delay) {
    const savedCallback = useRef();

    // Remember the latest callback.
    useEffect(() => {
        savedCallback.current = callback;
    }, [callback]);

    // Set up the interval.
    useEffect(() => {
        function tick() {
            savedCallback.current();
        }
        if (delay !== null) {
            let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
            return () => clearInterval(id);
        }
    }, [delay]);
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like the hook will only run once (on mount) if you put it directly in the body of the function (outside your own useEffect).

Comment: You cannot run them conditionally. Don't use them in the useEffect.

Comment: omg @Chris how did I not see that. Got so hung up on the error I didn't even consider if it needed to be in useEffect. If you put this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the hook logic is placed inside its own `useEffect`, and the callback stored persistently in with the help of `useRef` it will only run once during mount, which means you can put the hook in the function body directly, like so:

```
const LogConfirmation = props => {
  // props
  const { oldScore, newScore } = props;
  // local
  const [ score, setScore ] = useState(oldScore);
  const [ data, setData ] = useState(null);

  useInterval(()=>{
    setScore(score < newScore ? score + 1 : newScore);
  }, 100/((newScore - (score || 0))*Math.sqrt(.01)));

  // Rest of code
```